# Can I start an application in remote machine via RDP client?

Tags: remote-access, rdp, hyper-v

I am trying to development a tool to deploy environment with hyper-v, I need to create VMs with template and install specified software in the VM.

But, as I am using the same template so I cannot communicate via IP/hostname, and then I find out I can connect the VM via RDP by giving the VM's name like

```
axMsRdpClient8NotSafeForScripting1.AdvancedSettings2.RDPPort = 2179;
axMsRdpClient8NotSafeForScripting1.AdvancedSettings7.PCB = vmIDTextBox.Text;
```

although, I cannot run exe file using the api "ITSRemoteProgram RemoteProgram"

Does anyone knows how to do it? As I have to do it automatically, I cannot use the GUI console. Any suggestions are very appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows** remote computers, you could use **PsExec** from Microsoft SysInternals tools:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

It's free, very lightweight, and does what you want :-).

**For Linux,** you could use **SSH**. (which is also available for Windows, but you would need a daemon running on the destination machine, such as FreeSSHd).